# Reference entire row data or row-by-value from other sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-workspace, importrange

I've a Google Spreadsheet where my first sheet is a Products table.
The columns are SKU, Title, Price, Category, Type

I've some tasks in front of me where I need to create some bundles of different products. These varieres in number of products and categories and types.

I don't know if this is possible with the Spreadsheet app or I have to find alternative methods but I would love if I could reference e.g. the SKU number or the Title instead of my Sheet cell.

So, in a new sheet called **Bundle 01: Texture** instead of saying `=Products!A4` I somehow reference `=Products!SKU015` and then the entire row from Products is inserted.
I can make calculations and aggregates on the price/total price and other variables and should I change a Product row in **Products sheet* it will automatically update across all sheets in that spreadsheet.

Beside the benefits listed above it would also create an easy and quick overview of each bundle, both for myself but also for other actors which have interest in these.

The closets I've come to using data across one spreadsheet is https://support.google.com/docs/answer/75943 but this is just a reference to the cell.

Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: What's `SKU015` ? Try `INDEX/MATCH`

Comment: SKU015 was just an example of what I would like to reference instead of a cell number. The is just a product-ID which sits in the first column of my products sheet. I'll look into INDEX/MATCH and see what these guys are up to - thanks :)

Comment: "Any help is deeply appreciated." is not a practical, detailed question. Questions about handling data in Google Sheets should include sample input data and the expected results as text. As Google Sheets might be extended in multiple ways, it's necessary to specify if it's looking for a built-in feature or looking to use extensions like Google Apps Script or add-ons. On the other hand, Google Sheets have introduced several new features since 2018.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that the OP (Mestika) was needing [named ranges](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/63175?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en).

Comment: good answers quote from a link so that if the link rots the answer is still good.